# Exchange Web Service program work at development station but not on the other

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I wrote a program which work with Exchange Mailbox and it seems to work fine, 
but if i copy the .exe file from debug folder to another PC and run the .exe i got tis exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: COuld not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=15' ... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

I installed EWS Managed API and add reference to Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices in the project and on development machine it works fine. But when i run it on another PC it throw the reference error. Must i install that EWS Management API to production PC too or its only needed for development, how can i solve this error ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Installing Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.1 on client machine helped.